# VBA picture popup on click bug issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet in excel that list products and a picture for each product (Column D).  I have put the following code in the worksheet but my problem is this.

Problem: If a user clicks on a product image and then clicks on another image before clicking on a 2nd time to make the image small again the 2nd clicked image disappears and the 1st image adjusted to the new size and will only enlarge even bigger.

Image:

[Screenshot Steps of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ujUf.png)

```
Option Explicit
Dim fd As Boolean
Sub PicPopUp_Click()
fd = fd Xor True
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object
If fd Then
    .Left = .Left - 50
    .Width = .Width + 50
    .Top = .Top - 50
    .Height = .Height + 50
Else
    .Left = .Left + 50
    .Width = .Width - 50
    .Top = .Top + 50
    .Height = .Height - 50
End If
.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familair enough with your code.. But would it be possible to reset column D on every click on that column? I'm assuming that all the images are a standard size.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Nice Work!" 'place reset image size code here. 
Call "whatever your image resize macro is named"
End If
End Sub
```